# Cancel recurring meeting in lotus notes programatically

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I used ApptUNID to find the parent document.  Using this document reference, I have created a child document and set the NoticeType field to C and the document is sent to all participants.  By doing this, I was successful in deleting the calender entry form the participant's calender.  But I don't know, how to delete the calender entry for chair for the cancelled day.

How to cancel recurring meeting in lotus notes programatically using Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For recurring meetings the chair has (at least) two documents that are relevant here: 
There is the parent document (its Universalid is the ApptUNID) that "wraps" around all the stuff. And then there is at least ONE Response document that is shown in the views. Whenever you modify a single entry in the repeating dates, then the response- document will be split in at least two documents: one with all dates before the change, and one with all dates after the change (depending on your answer to the question WHAT to change).

This is something you have to handle when Canceling single entries from a recurring meeting. 
Basically "removing" one instance meens removing the date-/ time- entry from the corresponding multi value- items of the response- document as there are:

StartDate, StartDateTime, StartTime, EndDate, EndDateTime, EndTime, CalendarDate, CalendarDateTime, RepeatInstanceDates. 
DON't touch RepeatDates, as this is a "key"- field.

The same fields have to be taken into account on the parent- document.

I do not have in mind, which are the correct fields for you in that case.
To find out I would create a repeating meeting, and then export Parent document and response to XML. 
Then remove one entry and export again. By comparing the fields you should be able to identify the relevant Items.

If you want to learn more about Calendaring and scheduling in Lotus Notes, then read [this document](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/uafiles.nsf/docs/wpnotescsschema/%24file/csschema.pdf)